# Character columns being converted to numeric when appending to SQL Server Database with DBI package in R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dbi

I have a database hosted using Microsoft SQL Server. It has a table `project` with columns `project_id` (`int identity`), `project_code` (`nvarchar not null`), and `api_form` (`nvarchar`). I have connected to this using the `DBI` package in R and ran the following code.

```
dbAppendTable(conn, 'project', data.frame(
  project_code = c("ABC123", "DEF456"),
  api_form = c(NA, NA)
))
```

When I query the entire table however, I get the following output.

```
project_id  project_code    api_form
1   1   NULL
2   2   NULL
```

I am not sure why the characters are now integers. Is there a way to add character data directly to the table or, if this is expected behaviour, how do I query the table to find the actually text I entered?

Comment: This might be a factor issue. Try passing `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as argument in `data.frame()` call.

Comment: That's it. Too much work with tibbles has made me forget that that's the default behaviour. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic overlook of `data.frame()` call that casts strings as factors by default. Your `project_code` renders as factor (i.e., numeric columns with label values) and not characters. To resolve, simply pass `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, so actual character values are appended to database table:

```
dbAppendTable(conn, 'project', 
              data.frame(
                 project_code = c("ABC123", "DEF456"),
                 api_form = c(NA, NA),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE 
              )
)
```

Alternatively, set the argument as global option for all `data.frame()` calls in your R session:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dbAppendTable(conn, 'project', 
              data.frame(
                 project_code = c("ABC123", "DEF456"),
                 api_form = c(NA, NA) 
              )
)
```